# Switch Flash Player / HTML5 to use front camera

Tags: video, flash, webcam, camera

I have a Lenovo Helix which has 2 cameras, front and rear.

I need to take a picture of myself for a security verification on a site with a Flash player object to perform the capture. It's a similar flash webcam capture as something like ChatRoulette.

Flash by default wants to use my rear camera, but obviously I wish to use the front camera to take a picture of myself.

When I right click the flash object and go to the camera settings, I can choose the front camera in the dropdown box, and see myself in the little preview box. However, this does not actually change the camera input in the main window.

I am using the latest Chrome, version 32.

So, how do I properly switch the camera ad hoc? And how can I set my front camera as the default?

*Note: I will be asking in the Lenovo forums too, so please don't tell me to ask there instead. I would imagine this is a more general issue as many more devices have 2 cameras these days.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a small work around for this problem. Disable temporally the hardware driver of the rear camera.

In Windows, go to

Control Panel>Device Manager>Imaging Devices

Select the device for the rear webcam and choose "disable" in the tool bar. -*Very important*- Do not uninstall it, just disable it. You might need to reboot the system. Open again the website and it will choose by default the front camera. Once you completed your task, re-enable the device so that you can use it later.